# Removing all array items except one array item

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array structures. I want to delete all array items in both array except one item in both array. I have written my codes below. How can I do that?

```
$array_one = array(
   'image-one' => 'image-one.jpg',
   'image-two' => 'image-two.jpg',
   'image-three' => 'image-three.jpg',
   'image-four' => 'image-four.jpg',
   'image-five' => 'image-five.jpg',
   'image-six' => 'image-six.jpg',
   'image-seven' => 'image-seven.jpg',
);

$array_two = array(
   'image-one' => 'image-one.jpg',
   'image-two' => 'image-two.jpg',
   'image-three' => 'image-three.jpg',
   'image-four' => 'image-four.jpg',

);
```

I want to delete `image-one.jpg,image-two.jpg,image-three.jpg` in both arrays except `image-four.jpg,image-five.jpg,image-six.jpg,image-seven.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

Using unset:

```
unset($array['image-one']);
unset($array['image-two']);
unset($array['image-three']);
```

You can also create loop.

```
$todelete = array('image-one', 'image-two', 'image-three');
foreach($todelete as $del){
    unset($array[$del]);
}
```

If you want to delete by value:

```
$todelete = array('image-one.jpg', 'image-two.jpg', 'image-three.jpg');
foreach($todelete as $del){
  if(($key = array_search($del, $array)) !== false) {
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) :

```
unset($array_one['image-one']);
unset($array_one['image-two']);
unset($array_one['image-three']);
```

Comment: The same answer posted earlier.